# Creating/Displaying Interface Objects with Code for the iPhone [Objective-C]

Tags: objective-c, ios, object, dynamic, creation

I'm currently designing an app that calls for dynamically creating objects and then displaying them in a ViewController. My problem is wading through the documentation to try and create the objects I need. I've done some searching and even tried to just sit down and figure it out, but alas, I've got nothing to show for it. I already know how to dynamically create the ViewController but I can't seem to get any objects in it.

Does anyone know how I could go about creating objects (Say a button and a slider) dynamically with Objective-C in XCode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a button in code is simple

```
- (void)addButton {

    // Create button
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

    // Set the frame (location and size)
    [button setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 30)];

    // Set what happens when you touch the button
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    // Set button text
    [button.titleLabel setText:@"Button"];

    // Add button to view
    [self.view addSubview:button];

}
```

A lot of interface elements follow a similar patter- alloc and init the object, set the frame and add it to a view.

Comment: Thanks a lot Scott! I couldn't find a straight forward answer like the one you provided. I knew it was a lot simpler than I thought it was.

Comment: I'm used to using interface builder - I wanted the challenge of coding it myself, as well as needing to use it for my current project.

How would I go about releasing the dynamically created object?

Comment: Call [button removeFromSuperview] to remove it from the view hierarchy. You then need to release it if you previously retained it. You don't *have* to retain it if you don't need it to exist outside of it's superview, as the superview will retain it, just remember to set your pointer to nil after calling removeFromSuperview though, or you will be left with a dangling pointer.